# view.invalidate invokes redraw of other view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

If I invalidate view1 then my view2 is redrawn. I like to only redraw my view1.

I have:
2 Custom Views -> view1 & view2
1 LinearLayout

I visually switch between the view1 and view2 with:

```
LinearLayout.removeAllViews();
LinearLayout.addView(view2) or LinearLayout.addView(view1);
```

How can I invalidate view1 without triggering the drawing of view2 ?

Comment: Post code where you call invalidate. Why you removing and adding view. It would be easier to set visibility of them (VISIBLE, GONE).
I'm not understanding how view, that not added to layout is redrawing?

Comment: VISIBLE.GONE solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I post my comment as answer, mark it as solution for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to change visibility of views instead of remove and add to container. It will work faster and view with visibility gone will not redraw on invalidate.